# Dev Tools Crashing on Chrome Version 50.0.2661.102 m

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

So i have the following problem.

Any time i click on a request to view the headers/payload/response 
[image: Dev Tools Crash]
i receive a not responding window.
[image: Dev Tools - Not Responding]

If i wait ~2 minutes it works.

So what i receive here is a developer tools not responsive status when working on local machine.

I tried to re-install chrome. Nothing changed.

Current Version is: Version 50.0.2661.102 m listed as up to date.

Is there any possibility to get some logs or did anyone faced the same problem?

I think it can be relevant if i show what extensions i have installed.
[image: Extensions]

But i tried to enable/disable them and nothing changed.

And i get the same comportment in incognito mode too.

Later edit: I somehow identified the problem. Idea is that chrome is trying to display the cookie (request headers) which was 18k characters long and it looks like this is slowing a lot developer tools and sometimes make him crash.

I just saw that in Mozilla cookies are limited to a couple of characters (display perspective) and after that they show ...

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any known issues regarding this crash, so here are a couple of steps you could take:

1. Use the [Chrome Cleanup Tool](https://www.google.com/chrome/cleanup-tool/) and see if that helps.
2. Fully clean and re-install Chrome (including deleting user folders). If it works after that, you can slowly add extensions and plugins back and see if any reintroduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for involving into helping me. I tried the whole process. I'm ending up into the same situation. I was thinking that Chrome isn't dealing so well with big payloads. I tried with Mozilla and everything works smooth.