# Chrome inspect element freezes

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, bundle, inspect-element

I am working on a project of MVC. The css and js files are in bundle.

Ex: all.js.bundle (and this bundle contains all js) and

Ex: all.css.bundle (and this bundle contains all css).

Second thing i have just updated google chrome to 55.0.2883.87 m. After this update google debugger tools freezes while using css properties. Its too frustatiing. Any help.

Comment: try mozilla https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/

Comment: There can be multiple causes for this: Do you have an extension for KnockoutJs? Another thing that i found some time ago is the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37440953/dev-tools-crashing-on-chrome-version-50-0-2661-102-m

Comment: Solution: Getting Rid of bundle files. Thanks guys :)